# Prove $\operatorname{height}(P) \cdot \operatorname{width}(P) \geq |A|$ in partially ordered set?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, order-theory, discrete-geometry

Let $P = (A, \preceq)$ be a poset.

**Problem: Use Mirsky’s theorem to show $$\operatorname{height}(P) \cdot \operatorname{width}(P) \geq |A|.$$**

Please Note: Mirsky's Theorem is

> $\text{maximum size of a chain cover} = \text{minimum size of an anti chain}$

**My approach:**

If we partition $A$ into $k$ anti-chains, $A = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \cdots\cup A_k$.

Then, there exists

$$|A_i| \geq \frac{|A|}{\operatorname{height}(P)}$$
 I'm not sure this is correct and how do we come up with the width and height formula above?

Comment: @Shaun It's a complete problem. It doesn't require any further information or context to prove it.

Comment: It's a homework statement, and reads like one, @JohnBaek.  Homework, or simply self-study problem statements are okay *provided you've put in as much effort as you expect others to put in to hand you a solution you'll simply turn in as your own*.  I see no indication of effort from you, whatsoever.  This is not a "do my homework for me" site, despite a few rep-hunters who answer anything, but who's answers aren't trustworthy.  Please explore Help: How to ask a good question, and get rid of the attitude.

Comment: It still lacks context. Don't say I didn't warn you.

Comment: @amWhy I just edited my question with my approach (found the operation). I didn't want to make you feel bad. I thought it's complete but I was wrong. Can you help me on this problem? Maybe on editing or answering. Thanks - J.

Comment: @Shaun Let me know if this still lack context. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Yes, that's better.

Comment: This problem is hard, isn't it?

Comment: Huh??  The maximum chain cover size of the po with a < b is at least 3, {{a}, {b}, {a,b}} while the minimum antichange size is at most 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start to call your attention to the fact that your formulation of Mirsky's Theorem is wrong.
Here's what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirsky's_theorem#The_theorem) says about it:

> Mirsky's theorem states that, for every finite partially ordered set, the height also equals the minimum number of antichains (subsets in which no pair of elements are ordered) into which the set may be partitioned.

Notice that it could never be something like minimun size of an anti-chain, since that is always $1$ (or $0$, if your definition allows it).

---

So suppose $\mathrm{height}(P)=n$, and $\{A_1, \ldots, A_n\}$ is a partition of $P$ in which each $A_i$ is an anti-chain.
Each anti-chain has at most as many elements has $\mathrm{width}(P)$, by definition of width of a poset.
So
$$|P| = \sum_{i=1}^n|A_i| \leq n\cdot\mathrm{width}(P)=\mathrm{height}(P)\cdot\mathrm{width}(P).$$